# MySqlDataReader giving error at build with MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net

I got [this Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQGdO.png)!

Please someone could be helpme to perform the query and read the data

Thanks

Comment: That's looks like part of a stack trace only.  Give us the error message, the full stack trace and the code containing the error.

Comment: OK, now that I edited your post so that it is readable I can see that you actually provided a link to an image that provides the full error message and the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a data reader by invoking a constructor.  The way to create a data reader is to call `ExecuteReader` on a command object.

I see that you actually have some code that does that commented out.  That suggests to me that you don't understand declarations and constructors.  This:

```
Dim someVariable As SomeType
```

is a variable declaration.  It includes the `Dim` keyword, the variable name and the data type.  That's all that is in a declaration.

You can also initialise a variable when you declare it, using any expression that evaluates to an object of the specified type.  To create a new object of that type, you use the `New` keyword to invoke a constructor:

```
Dim someVariable As SomeType = New SomeType
```

As you can see, that code declares a variable, creates an object and assigns the object to the variable.  VB also provides a shorthand for that:

```
Dim someVariable As New SomeType
```

So, you only use the `New` keyword to create a new object and assign it to the variable.  It is NOT part of the declaration.  If all you want is to declare a variable then do just that and DO NOT create an object.  In your case, the object is created later, when you call `ExecuteReader` on the command.